# Expectation Values of a Binomial Distribution with an Exponentially Distributed Variable

Tags: binomial-distribution, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I have an exponentially distributed variable, $Y$:

$Y \sim Exp(\lambda_{0}, x) $

I want to calculate the expectation value of a binomial distributed variable $Z$ dependent upon the value of $Y$ given by:

$Z \sim B(N, k,  p = 1 - e^{- \lambda_{1}Y})$

My intuition tells me that in order to solve $E[Z]$, I should:

- take the expectation value of $Y$, $E[Y] = \frac{1}{\lambda_{0}}$;
- substitute into $Z$, $Z \sim B(N, k,  p = 1 - e^{-\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{0}}})$
- take the expectation value of $Z$, $E[Z] = n(1 - e^{-\frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{0}}})$

However, something tells me this is too simple and therefore probably wrong, given my limited knowledge of statistics.

Can someone reveal to me how I would solve this problem?

Edit: I tested numerically, and I found the result to be incorrect. I am not surprised, yet I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: You have an exponential-binomial compound distribution ([compounds are also known as "mixtures"](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/1352)); searching for these terms may be helpful, although I didn't find anything at short notice, and most of what I did find looked at "the other kind" of compounds: having $X_1, \dots, X_n\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$, where $n\sim\text{Binom}(N,k,p)$ - not what you are looking for.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I am currently looking here for inspiration: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159225/variance-of-compound-distribution?rq=1

Comment: As you have found, you can't just substitute one expectation into the formula for the expectation of the other component when looking for the expectation of a [compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution). You will need to integrate over the entire distribution of $Y$ to get the PMF of $Z$, then take the expectation by summing that one.

Comment: Well, that question is related, but again not the same, because the compounding here happens of the number of trials in the binomial, not the probability as in your problem...

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks - I have simply never heard of compound distributions before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key idea: condition on the value of $Y$.

In more detail: $E[Z]=E[E[Z|Y]]$ by the law of total expectation. Conditional on $Y=y$, we know that the expected value of $Z$ is $n(1 - e^{- \lambda_{1}y})$.

So $E[Z]=E[n(1-e^{-\lambda_1 Y})]=n-nE[e^{-\lambda_1 Y}]$.The latter expectation is just the moment generating function of the exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda_0$, evaluated at $-\lambda_1$ (see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) for the mgf of the exponential distribution). So, finally, $E[Z]=n-n\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_0+\lambda_1}=\frac{n\lambda_1}{\lambda_0+\lambda_1}$.

Comment: An excellently explained answer. Having had a grand total of five minutes exposure to compound distributions, thanks to your answer I feel much more comfortable with how one solves a problem like this. However, I would certainly not have known about the moment generating function of the exponential used in this solution. Thank you for this very enlightening answer! (I have tested this numerically, it yields the correct answer.)